# Android - ImageView as Offline map

Tags: android, dictionary, imageview, offline, marker

I am trying to implement an offline map content into my android app. I need not so much detailed map just for a specific area and mark some places over it. a zoomable and scrollable image seems to be enough for me.

First question is;
1-) what is the best option for offline map in android? My constraint is that my app couldn't use any internet connection. Do I have to use an imageview (by adding button markers on it) or can I use any offline data for Mapview?

I have searched a lot for using imageview as map but couldn't get so much result.

my basic question for imageview is;
2-) How can I add a marker(a button) on a specific position of imageview?

I have found some sample code for scrolling and zoom and implemented them (Scrollview has no diagonal scroll as default) but I couldn't find a way to add marker to an scrollable, zoomable imageview.

Please don't think on sample code, just assume that imageview is in an scrollview and I try to add a marker(button) on it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: how exactly do you implement zoom ? you need to replace image upon zooming in unless you got map rendering engine that can take vectorial data and transform it into a bitmap and use it (like iGO des). regarding adding markers, basically scroll view extends FrameLayout and can take only one child so you must put either a framelayout OR absolute layout so you can place views anywhere. then you can add your image either as background or place the imageview to fill the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other options such as OSMDroid: But personal experience of this library would recommend using an imageview if you can and don't require zooming in and out and having performance issue.

You can have a scrollview, containing a horizontal scrollview, which can then contain a relative layout with an imageview taking up the space. Then add the markers to the relative layout and position accordingly.

Comment: thank you very much (: it really helped me.
Is there any way to implement diagonal scroll with scrollviews?

Comment: The combination of HorizontalScrollView and ScrollView will give you diagonal scrolling, but you may need to pass the touch events from the root scrollview down to the child scrollview